# Is there any way to receive flatten data using facebook graphQL?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have just figured out, that there is such an amazing thing like GraphQL. I am curious if there is any way when using this:

`fields=id,name,description,place{name,location{city}},cover{source}`

to get this:

```
{
  "id": "100107243793441",
  "name": "Demoni Italiani live at Red Pub",
  "description": "",
  "place": "Redpub Sedico",
  "city": "Belluno",
  "cover": "https:..."
}
```

instead of this:

```
{
   "id": "100107243793441",
   "name": "Demoni Italiani live at Red Pub",
   "description": "",
   "place": {
      "name": "Redpub Sedico",
      "location": {
         "city": "Belluno"
      },
      "id": "1255751344441946"
   },
   "cover": {
      "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/14519891_1118974604877184_8278251704306008958_n.jpg?oh=b564087098074d40b467e89d11d60874&oe=58650DC3",
      "id": "1118974604877184"
   }
}
```

Maybe some aliasing exists?

Comment: What does `fields=id,name,description,place{name,location{city}},cover{source}` represent? The internal backend object structure/fields or the `GraphQLObjectType`'s fields?